# I am little confused about Zend OPCache Configuration

Tags: php, zend-framework, opcache

In the important notice section of [this article](https://www.activecollab.com/blog/3-zend-opcache-memcache) it says:

> Setting `opcache.validate_timestamps` to `0` (disabling it) will
>   increase the performance, especially when you have an application with
>   a lot of files, but it also means you have to reset the OPcache
>   manually when you alter the application files.
>
> If not fully understood, `opcache.validate_timestamps=0` can break
>   your application or cause hard to find issues.
>
> The configuration above is for benchmarking only. For your production
>   environments please use following values (note the
>   `opcache.validate_timestamps=1` part):

I'm not able to understand what it's trying to say. It would be great if anybody could explain the above statement. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OPCache will check for updated files at certain interval. The interval can be specified using `opcache.validate_timestamps`.

I.e. If you set `opcache.validate_timestamps = 1` and `opcache.revalidate_freq = 5` OPCache will check for updated files every 5 seconds.

Now if you set its value to 0. OPCache will not check for updated files. This means that when you update a file, rather then loading the updated file OPCache will still load old cached file. And you'll have to manually reset the OPCache using `opcache_reset(), opcache_invalidate()` in order to reflect your changes.

Here's a link from the PHP Manual.

[opcache.validate_timestamps](http://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.validate-timestamps)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Now i understood what it's trying to say

Comment: `opcache.validate_timestamps` is a boolean. In order to check for updated files every 5 seconds you would set `opcache.validate_timestamps=1` and `opcache.revalidate_freq=5`.